# Using datagram sockets between android app and java program

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming, udp

I a having some serious problems, communicating between my android app and my java program with datagram sockets. My android app should be the client and have the following code for socket etc.:

```
    try {
        InetAddress ipAdress        = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        int portNo                  = 4324;
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        String sendString           = "&%#!check_connection!#%&";
        DatagramPacket packet       = new DatagramPacket(sendString.getBytes(), sendString.length(), ipAdress, portNo);             
        clientSocket.send(packet);

        // Receive response

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My java program should receive it like this:

```
while(waitingForClient) {
                            try {
                                System.out.println("test 1");
                                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                                System.out.println("test 2");
                                serverSocket.receive(packet);
                                System.out.println("test 3");
                                String getData = new String(packet.getData());
                                System.out.println(getData);
                                mainFrame.logArea.append(getData + "\n");

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
```

All of the code in the android app is executed, but in my java program's code, it only reaches "test 2" (never prints out test 3)...

Both my android devices and my pc is connected to the same router..

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InetAddress ipAdress        = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
```

your android app is trying to connect to itself, pass in the ip address of the computer running the java program

Comment: But if I want to use this only locally, isn't getLocalHost() right?
I did also try InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"); .. with same result

Comment: @user68621 `127.0.0.1` is the local host address which is the address of the device running the code. This is not the address of anything connected to your wifi router. You are sending a message from the android app to the android phone.

Comment: Yea i know, I just thought it should be done like this when both ends are connected to the samme network... So how do I get the ip adress of the receiving java program?

Comment: @user68621 no, client needs to know the address of the server. the address is not localHost, unless your running a server on the same machine for some reason. Short term to test your code, find your machines ip address and hardcode it. Long term this is a massive question, are you going to have a static ip? are you implementing bonjour? are you sending out broadcasts on a network. The answer to your question as mentioned above is your using the wrong IP. Please mark this as top answer and research technologies for discovering a server based on your requirements

Comment: @user68621 don't forget to mark top answer / upvote questions that solve your issue. Others facing the same problem will want to know what fixed it for you

Comment: I tried using my machines ip adress witout any luck.. which i think is really weird. For long term use I would think a broadcast would be the most appropiate solution. Never used broadcast's before though. Do you know any good and well explained tutorials?

Comment: @user68621 you are sending to port no. 4324, I don't see that being used anywhere in the server code. Are you setting  up your server correctly to listen on that port? Your asking 2 different questions now, both whats wrong with this code and how do I do something else entirely. I only answered this question because I saw the ip address mistake. If you have further issues please ask another question and provide more details of what you are trying to achieve. A quick google threw this up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999425/simple-udp-broadcast-client-and-server-on-different-machines

Comment: Okay i'll give it a shot. And if im still having problems, I will ask another question. Thansk for your help