# Getting IP Address of another device (Sever) in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to build an android application that connects two or more devices as a client/server(using socket).

But problem is in client device user need to manually put IP address of Server device to connect with server. But from the client i don't know the server IP Address. and i don't want to enter it manually.

is there any way to get IP address(programmatically) of server device that using same application and on the same network ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank in advanced.

Comment: You could implement a discovery service. That is: you broadcast (UDP, fire&forget) the server info on the net (but do not "spam"). Clients can listen for those broadcasts and build a list of accessible servers from those.

Comment: I don't know if [Beacons](https://developers.google.com/beacons/) may also be an option for you.

Comment: There is even a Protocol for this: [SSDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Fildor , I studied little bit about Discovery Service. But still i am not clear about it and don't understand how to start with UDP.
If you give me any document or related sample code it will be very helpful for me. :)

Comment: http://michieldemey.be/blog/network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999425/simple-udp-broadcast-client-and-server-on-different-machines ... for more: https://www.google.de/#q=java+udp+discovery

Comment: Thanks again. @Fildor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many ways finally, I have got a solution which is

> Network discovery using UDP broadcast (credit goes to [this documentation](https://michieldemey.be/blog/network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast/))

(Thanks @Fildor for your suggestion to implement this service).

**Solution**

Using UDP packets and broadcasting them! This technique however is not optimal, but as long as we stay in one network this shouldn’t be a problem.
UDP packets however are fairly easy to work with.

**Server implementation**

- Open a socket on the server that listens to the UDP requests.
- Make a loop that handles the UDP requests and responses
- Inside the loop, check the received UPD packet to see if it’s valid
- Still inside the loop, send a response to the IP and Port of the
  received packet

**Client implementation**

- Open a socket on a random port.
- Try to broadcast to the default broadcast address (255.255.255.255)
- Loop over all the computer’s network interfaces and get their
  broadcast addresses
- Send the UDP packet inside the loop to the interface’s broadcast
  address
- Wait for a reply
- When we have a reply, check to see if the package is valid
- When it’s valid, get the package’s sender IP address; this is the
  server’s IP address
- CLOSE the socket! We don’t want to leave open random ports on someone
  else’s computer